# __str__ returning one giant string instead of individual values. New to Python

Tags: python

```
class CovidRecord:

def __init__(self, pruid, prname, prnameFR, date, update, numcomf, numprob, numdeaths, numtotal):
    self.pruid = pruid
    self.prname = prname
    self.prnameFR = prnameFR
    self.date = date
    self.update = update
    self.numconf = numcomf
    self.numprob = numprob
    self.numdeaths = numdeaths
    self.numtotal = numtotal

def __str__(self):
    return self.pruid + self.prname + self.prnameFR + self.date + self.update + self.numconf + self.numprob + self.numdeaths + self.numtotal`

def write_to_dataframe(self):

    dataframe = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\jakev\Downloads\covid19-download.csv')
    dataframetop = dataframe.head(6)

    print('Please insert information to add')
    pruid = input('Province ID: ')
    prname = input('Province name: ')
    prnameFR = input('Province name in French: ')
    date = input('Date: ')
    update = input('When was it updated: ')
    numcomf = input('Confirmed cases: ')
    numprob = input('Probable cases: ')
    numdeaths = input('Number of deaths ')
    numtotal = input('Total number')
    newrecord = CovidRecord(pruid, prname, prnameFR, date, update, numcomf, numprob, numdeaths, numtotal)

    dfobj = pd.DataFrame(newrecord, columns = ['prvid', 'prname', 'prnameFR', 'date', 'update', 'numcomf', 'numprob'
        , 'numdeaths', 'numtotal', 'newrecord'], index=['1'])

    newdataframe = dataframetop.append(dfobj, ignore_index = True)

    print(newdataframe)
```

CovidRecord is a record object I've created to load additional records into a dataframe. When I input the responses to the inputs in the terminal, it prints out a giant String with each of my responses under every single column instead of separating them into their individual rightful columns. How can I make it so that when I enter the "prvname" it puts my answer only under province name and so on? Below is an example of the output I get.

```
pruid                                       prname                                     prnameFR                                         date 
0   35.0                                      Ontario                                      Ontario                                   2020-01-31  
1   59.0                             British Columbia                         Colombie-Britannique                                   2020-01-31 
6    NaN  23OntarioOntario2021-02-182021-02-182334278  23OntarioOntario2021-02-182021-02-182334278  23OntarioOntario2021-02-182021-02-182334278
```

the bottom record being the one I attempted to insert. It taking all my answers to each input, putting them into 1 String and then putting that one giant string into each column.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of `CovidRecord`?? Why are you creating a custom class and trying to put that into a dataframe?

Comment: None of this has *anything* to do with your `__str__` implementation, why do you think that's relevant?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga CovidRecord is supposed to be a DTO/ Record object. It's a requirement for my assignment to use one. I could definitely complete this task without it a lot more easily, but the it seems as though I need to use one.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Also, I don't know that it has anything to do with my __str__ implementation. I honestly have no clue what the issue is, I looked up a similar project on github and he seems to do basically the exact same thing as me with completely different results. I don't know what the issue is. I'd be willing to rewrite the entire function to get it to work, it's possible I simply didn't chose the right way to do it.

Comment: Why are you using a DTO with *pandas*? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Can you tell me why it doesn't make sense?

Comment: Because *there is no sense in it*, why don't you tell me why you *think it makes sense*? Replace `newrecord = CovidRecord(...)` with just `newrecord = [...]` Basically, why do you *expect* pandas to treat your random object as a row? Pandas has a well-defined interface for how to do that, it generally requires a *sequence*, usually a `list` for doing what you want to do, although, a `dict` also works. Why do you expect `pandas` to be able to work with a `CovidRecord`?

Answer (score 1):

> **str** returning one giant string

You are putting them together yourself with following line:

> `return self.pruid + self.prname + self.prnameFR + self.date + self.update + self.numconf + self.numprob + self.numdeaths + self.numtotal`

Comment: When I do that I get the following error "TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)"

Comment: @jakeyv i know, that's why I removed it again. I do not know a solution for your special case, I only told you what you did wrong

Comment: @jakeyv It’s unclear exactly why you want to try to return a non-string-type object from a `__str__` method...

Comment: @esqew I am to blame for that, because i provided an example doing exactly that ... lol